# Строка состояние загрузки

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Создаю `Notification` для загрузки файла

```
private void downloadFile(String url) {

              new AsyncTask<String, Integer, File>() {

               private Exception m_error = null;
               private static final int NOTIFY_ID = 1;
               NotificationManager myNotificationManager;
               Notification notification;
               Context context;
               @Override
               protected void onPreExecute() {

                 myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
                int icon = android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download; 
                CharSequence tickerText = ""; 
                long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
                context=getApplicationContext();
                notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, WebBrawser.class);
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
                RemoteViews contentView;
                contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification); 
                contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.progressBar1, 100, 0, false);
                contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.name,"FILENAME.mp3"); 
                notification.contentIntent = contentIntent; 
                notification.contentView = contentView; 
                myNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);

               }
```

Обновляю `ProgressBar`

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(final Integer... values) {
               new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                     int progress=(int) ((values[0] / (float) values[1]) * 100);
                                        Integer textProgress=new Integer(progress);
                                       notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.progressBar1, 100, progress, false);
                                       notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.progress, textProgress.toString()+"%");
                                       myNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }).start();

          }
```

Но при начале загрузки приложение виснет, обновление выполняю в отдельном потоке. Загрузка файла без `Notification` выполняется правильно. Помогите разобраться, что не так сделал.

Comment: а зачем вы в onProgressUpdate создаете поток? этот обработчик выполняется в главном потоке. попробуйте задавать прогресс непосредственно, без дополнительного потока.

Comment: пыталься тоже самое,думал если обновление вынесу в отдельный поток то эффективнее будет.

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл причину зависания. Проблема была из за многократного вызова

```
publishProgress(downloadedSize, totalSize);

    int updateProgressBool=(int) ((downloadedSize/(double)totalSize) * (double)100);
                  if (updateProgressBool >=a)
                  {
                      System.out.println(updateProgressBool);
                      a+=5;
                    previusProgressBool=updateProgressBool;
                    publishProgress(downloadedSize, totalSize);

                  }
```

Исправил так, чтобы прогресс обновлялся каждые 5% загруженного файла.